# The Javascript "apply" function doesn't exist in window.external extension object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, external

I'm using javascript extension (AKA *window.external*) on IE8 (might as well be any IE version) to expose certain functions.
I'm trying to call the *apply* function, which is (supposed to be, according to [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx)) natively embedded in every JS function, on a *window.external* object's function, but the browser keep throwing exception that the *apply* function doesn't exist for that function.

For example, this code works:

```
function onDataReceived(url, success, status, data, errorMessage) {
    alert(onDataReceived);
}

function innerTest() {
    alert(arguments[0] + ", " + arguments[1]);
}

function outerTest() {
    innerTest.apply(null, arguments);
}

outerTest("hello", "world");

// alerts "hello, world"
```

But This code throws exception:

```
function outerTest() {
    window.external.innerTest.apply(null, arguments); // <-- exception
}

outerTest("hello", "world");
```

Bottom line is - I need to pass an unknown number of arguments to the external function, and so far i've reached a dead end...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I accepted Mike Samuel's answer since (as far as i understand) the `apply` function doesn't exist in the `window.external` object, because it's not a native javascript object.
What Mike suggested as the "worst case" is what I ended up doing, for the moment.
thanks

Comment: Is `window.external.innerTest` really a function? What does `typeof window.external.innerTest` show? Is it callable if you use `window.external.innerTest()`?

Comment: @duri - `typeof window.external` is "object", but `typeof window.external.innerTest` is unknown. when i call `window.external.innTest(param1, param2)` it works fine. it's because the function in implemented natively (C++, through the browser's COM object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a general solution. A simple example is like below:

```js
function invoke (funcName, ...args) {
    var argStr = '';
    for (let i in args) {
        argStr += ', this.args[' + i + ']';
    }
    return (new Function('return window.external[\'' + funcName + '\'](' + argStr.substring(2) + ')')).bind({args})();
}

// define a circular structure which cannot be stringified:
const a = {}; a.a = a;

// make a call:
invoke('foo', 10, 'abc', new Date(), function(){}, a);

// equivalent to:
window.external.foo(10, 'abc', new Date(), function(){}, a);
```

As you can see, there is no necessary to keep the parameters serializable.

**The main idea is properly specifying the context, and mounting all the parameters onto that context**.

I used ES6 syntax here just to make the code easier to understand. And of course, to make it work in IE8, you can translate it to ES5-compatible syntax and you might have ES5 shim included first to polyfill `Function.prototype.bind`. OR, you just never need `bind` at all:

**EDIT: ES5 compatible version:**

```js
function invoke (funcName) {
    var argStr = '';
    for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        argStr += ', this.args[' + i + ']';
    }
    return {
        args: arguments,
        func: new Function('return window.external[\'' + funcName + '\'](' + argStr.substring(2) + ')')
    }.func();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If `window.external` is a host object, or from some extension mechanism that doesn't want its prototype exposed to page logic, then it may be a function but may not have the usual `call` and apply members.  Luckily, you can call `call` and apply `apply`:

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(window.external, null, [argumentsToExtension])
```

or to be really meta,

```
Function.prototype.apply.apply(window.external, [null, [argumentsToExtension]])
```

where `null` is what is passed as the value of `this` which should be interpreted as `window` by the usual call/apply rules.

EDIT:

If that doesn't work, you can always fall back to the triangle of hackery.

```
function triangleOfHackery(obj, methodName, args) {
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0: return obj[methodName]();
    case 1: return obj[methodName](args[0]);
    case 2: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1]);
    case 3: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mike Samuel - thanks, really creative thinking. unfortunately, this doesn't work. it does work on simple JS functions, but not on `window.external` function. here's what i tried (and failed): `Function.prototype.apply.apply(window.external.innerTest, [null, [param1, param1]]);`. if i replace _window.external.innerTest_ with, say, _funcSimple_ - it works fine.

Comment: @Omri, does it work if you replace the null with `window.external`?  That way it will receive the same `this` that it would when you call it normally.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, yes, i did try it (sorry i forgot to mention it earlier), with: `Function.prototype.apply.apply(window.external.innerTest, [window.external, [param1, param2]]);`, but again - no luck. i think it's because _window.external_ is an extension object, so it's not a native JS object, and that's the root of what i'm experiencing.

Comment: @Omri, please see my edit.  Above is an absolutely horrible way to get reflective `apply` style parameter list passing for the `new` operator.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, thanks, but that's exactly what i did :) i was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: This worked great for me was trying to do Math.max.apply in ie8

Comment: What about `new Function('return window.external[\'' + funcName + '\'](' + argStr + ')')();`

Comment: @shuangwhywhy, that only allows passing arguments that can be serialized so is not a general solution

Comment: @MikeSamuel There is a way to work around. Since I can't post the whole solution here, I posted an answer below. Please check.